# How to perform a case-insensitive search for files of a given suffix?

Tags: python, regex, string, case-insensitive, ends-with

I'm looking for the equivalent of `find $DIR -iname '*.mp3'`, and I don't want to do the kooky `['mp3', 'Mp3', MP3', etc]` thing. But I can't figure out how to combine the `re*.IGNORECASE` stuff with the simple `endswith()` approach. My goal is to not miss a single file, and I'd like to eventually expand this to other media/file types/suffixes.

```
import os
import re
suffix = ".mp3"

mp3_count = 0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Volumes/audio"):
    for file in files:
        # if file.endswith(suffix):
        if re.findall('mp3', suffix, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
            mp3_count += 1

print(mp3_count)
```

TIA for any feedback

Comment: Does it have to be a regex solution? Why not `pathlib.Path(file).suffix.lower() == '.mp3'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :)

```
import os
# import re
suffix = "mp3"

mp3_count = 0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Volumes/audio"):
    for file in files:
        # if file.endswith(suffix):
        if file.split('.')[-1].lower() == suffix:
            mp3_count += 1

print(mp3_count)
```

Python's `string.split()` will separate the string into a list, depending on what parameter is given, and you can access the suffix by `[-1]`, the last element in the list

Comment: Thanks. Simple, and it was the only suggestion I could get to actually work.

Answer (score 14):

Don't bother with `os.walk`. Learn to use [the easier, awesome `pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead. Like so:

```
from pathlib import Path

suffix = ".mp3"

mp3_count = 0

p = Path('Volumes')/'audio': # note the easy path creation syntax
# OR even:
p = Path()/'Volumes'/'audio': 

for subp in p.rglob('*'): #  recursively iterate all items matching the glob pattern
    # .suffix property refers to .ext extension
    ext = subp.suffix
    # use the .lower() method to get lowercase version of extension
    if ext.lower() == suffix: 
        mp3_count += 1

print(mp3_count)
```

"One-liner", if you're into that sort of thing (multiple lines for clarity):

```
sum(1 for subp in (Path('Volumes')/'audio').rglob('*')
     if subp.suffix.lower() == suffix)
```

Comment: Great suggestion by @Rawing to use `.rglob()` rather than `iterdir()`. I've edited the answer to do that instead.

Comment: Nice, modern answer. FWIW, if doing further operations like checking if `ext` is in a list of possible extensions, that the variable `ext` includes the period. So `.mp3` and not `mp3`.

Comment: Also I really appreciate the non-regex, pure-python, answer

Answer (score 1):

The regex equivalent of `.endswith` is the `$` sign.

To use your example above, you could do this;

```
re.findall('mp3$', suffix, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
```

Though it might be more accurate to do this;

```
re.findall(r'\.mp3$', suffix, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
```

which makes sure that the filename ends with `.mp3` rather than picking up files such as `test.amp3`.

This is a pretty good example of a situation that doesn't really require regex - so while you're welcome to learn from these examples, it's worth considering the alternatives provided by other answerers.